# Reverse fourier transformation of exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-function

What is the result to this formula:
$$F^{-1}\left(\exp(\hat{f})\right)$$
with $F^{-1}$ the inverse fourier transformation? I tried to start with
$$F^{-1} = \int\exp\left(\hat{f}(\omega)\right)\cdot\exp\left(2\cdot\pi\cdot i\cdot \omega\cdot x\right)d\omega\\
= \int \exp\left(\hat{f}(\omega)+2\cdot\pi\cdot i\cdot\omega\cdot x\right) d\omega
$$
but now I am stuck. Is it possible to continue without knowing the fourier transformed function?

Comment: This looks very unnatural to me. Do oyou mind telling where such a situation did arise? (No, I have never seen any formula for the inverse Fourier transform of $\exp(\hat f)$.)

Comment: I am currently at the situation of calculating a part of the GNLSE, and I was thinking about one potential algorithm. But if that is not possible, then I have to find another way.